# c++ 前方宣言でunique_ptrをメンバに持った場合のエラー(error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'B')

Tags: c++, c++11

unique_ptrでコンパイルエラーが出て、調べても分からないので質問させてください。

A.h

```
#include <memory>
class B;

class A {

    public:
        static std::unique_ptr<A> create();

    private:
        void init();
        std::unique_ptr<B> _b;

};
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
std::unique_ptr<A> A::create() {
    std::unique_ptr<A> ptr(new A);
    ptr->init();
    return ptr;
}

void A::init() {
    _b = B::create();
}
```

B.h

```
#include <memory>

class B {
    public:
    static std::unique_ptr<B> create();
};
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"

std::unique_ptr<B> B::create() {
        std::unique_ptr<B> ptr(new B);
        return ptr;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

int main(void) {
    auto a = A::create();
    return 0;
}
```

以下のようなエラーが出ます

```
    clang++ A.cpp B.cpp main.cpp -std=c++11
    In file included from main.cpp:1:
    In file included from ./A.h:1:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2395:27: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'B'
                            static_assert(sizeof(_Tp) > 0, "default_delete can not delete incomplete type");
                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2603:13: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::default_delete<B>::operator()' requested here
                            __ptr_.second()(__tmp);
                            ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2571:46: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::unique_ptr<B, std::__1::default_delete<B> >::reset' requested here
            _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY ~unique_ptr() {reset();}
                                                                                             ^
    ./A.h:4:7: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::unique_ptr<B, std::__1::default_delete<B> >::~unique_ptr' requested here
    class A {
                ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2603:13: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::default_delete<A>::operator()' requested here
                            __ptr_.second()(__tmp);
                            ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:2571:46: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::unique_ptr<A, std::__1::default_delete<A> >::reset' requested here
            _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY ~unique_ptr() {reset();}
                                                                                             ^
    main.cpp:4:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::unique_ptr<A, std::__1::default_delete<A> >::~unique_ptr' requested here
        auto a = A::create();
                         ^
    ./A.h:2:7: note: forward declaration of 'B'
    class B;
                ^
    1 error generated.
```

A.hでBの前方宣言ではなく、include B.hをすればエラーは出なくなりますが、
こうするしかないのでしょうか？
shared_ptrに変更した場合にはエラーは出ません。

このエラーで調べると、Pimpleに関する話題しか出なくて困っています。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4):

[Pimpleに関する話題で出てくる回答](https://qiita.com/false-git@github/items/79bf1b6acc00dc43d173#comment-9071ab88afe79f2cf834)の通り、Aのデストラクタを非インライン化すれば[コンパイルできます](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AltLgDb9coJiVD3a)。

A.h

```cpp
#include <memory>
class B;

class A {

    public:
        static std::unique_ptr<A> create();
        ~A(); // デストラクタを非インライン化

    private:
        void init();
        std::unique_ptr<B> _b;

};
```

A.cpp

```cpp
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
std::unique_ptr<A> A::create() {
    std::unique_ptr<A> ptr(new A);
    ptr->init();
    return ptr;
}

A::~A() = default; // デストラクタを非インライン化

void A::init() {
    _b = B::create();
}
```

参考：

- [unique_ptr はクラスの正確なサイズを知らないといけない? - Qiita](https://qiita.com/false-git@github/items/79bf1b6acc00dc43d173)

Comment: ありがとうございます。その方法で問題なくコンパイルできました。ふと疑問に思ったのですが、今回の場合、なぜunique_ptrの場合はコンパイルできないが、shared_ptrであればコンパイルできるのでしょうか。

Comment: 書籍「[Effective Modern C++](https://www.oreilly.co.jp/books/9784873117362/) 項目22：Pimpl イディオムを用いる際は特殊メンバ関数を定義する」でまさにこの話題が取り上げられています。こちらの[スライド](https://www.slideshare.net/KeisukeFukuda/effective-modern-c-item-22)もご参考に。

Answer (score 2):

STLの`std::unique_ptr<T>`がテンプレートクラスとしてすべてインラインで定義されており、`delete T`から最終的に`T`のデストラクターを呼び出します。そのため`T`（質問の例では`B`）が定義されなおかつデストラクターがアクセス可能であることが条件となります。

Pimplを使う方法もありますが、どうしてもということでしたら、どこかでインライン定義せず宣言と分離することです。影響範囲を狭めるのであれば`std::default_delete<B>::operator()`を分離することでしょうか。

A.hにて`std::unique_ptr<B>`よりも手前の位置で

```
namespace std {
    template<> struct default_delete<B> {
        constexpr default_delete() noexcept = default;
        void operator()(B* ptr) const noexcept;
    };
}
```

と特殊化しておき、B.cppで

```
void std::default_delete<B>::operator()(B * ptr) const noexcept { delete ptr; }
```

と定義すればクラス`B`との依存関係を分離できます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。そのような方法もあるのですね。非常に参考になりました。

Answer (score -1):

[`unique_ptr`の説明](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/memory/unique_ptr.html)を見る限り、テンプレートの第2引数D(のデフォルト)である`default_delete<T>`クラスでは`T`が完全型であることを要求しているように見えます。

[`default_delete<T>`の説明](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/memory/default_delete.html)より引用

> 型Tが不完全型である場合、operator()の実行は不適格となる。

ですので、`unique_ptr`のテンプレート`T`を前方宣言できないのは仕様と思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考になりました。